# Can't place this table where I want to

Tags: tables

[This example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354490/vertical-align-the-content-of-the-table) is fine, but there is a small problem: I can't place the table where I want to. For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{5pt}

\begin{document}
This text should be above
    \begin{table}[]
\centering
    \caption{Gruppo 6}
    \label{my-label}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{ | >{\centering}p{2.75cm} | *{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.75cm} |}}
    \hline\hline
\textbf{Title / Title} & \textbf{X}    & \textbf{Y}    & \textbf{Z}    \\   \hline\hline
\textbf{A}  & a\%           & b\%           & c\%           \\  \hline
\textbf{B}  & d\%           & e\%           & f\%           \\  \hline
\textbf{C}  & g\%           & h\%           & i\%           \\  \hline
\textbf{D}  & j\%           & k\%           & l\%           \\  \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use option `[h]`.

Comment: In addition to the long answer of how to position the float, the short answer to that question also points out that you may not need the table environment.